# pgfkeys - is choice + value pass to graphicx

Tags: pgfkeys, key-value

I'm trying to implement a macro which is a wrapper over the graphicx `\includegraphics` command (because I'd like to pass the parameters for cropping in a key-value fashion). While doing so, at first I introduced a key to set the `width` (option of `includegraphics`). Later on I needed the same macro where I set the `scale` and `height` option.

Now I have three macros doing basically the same which I'd like to merge into one. I saw there is the `.is choice` key which I tried using, but there I fail to additionally pass a value and later on passing the key-value pair to graphicx. But see my try:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% \pgfkeys{
%   /testing/.cd,
%   scaling/.is choice,
%   scaling/width/.code=\def\testing{width=#1},
%   scaling/height/.code=\def\testing{height=#1},
%   scaling/scale/.code=\def\testing{scale=#1},
% }

\pgfkeys{
    /graphicx/.cd,
    left/.initial=0cm, left/.default=0cm,
    % left/.store in=\owngraphicx@left,
    right/.initial=0cm, right/.default=0cm,
    top/.initial=0cm, top/.default=0cm,
    bottom/.initial=0cm, bottom/.default=0cm,
    page/.initial={1}, page/.default={1},
    width/.initial=\linewidth, width/.default=\linewidth,
}
\newcommand{\slidesS}[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/graphicx/.cd,left,right,top,bottom,page,#1}%
    \fbox{%
        \includegraphics[%
        page=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/page},%
        scale=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/width},%
        clip,%
        trim=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/left} \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/bottom} \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/right} \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/top},%
        ]{#2}%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\slidesW}[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/graphicx/.cd,left,right,top,bottom,page,#1}%
    \fbox{%
        \includegraphics[%
        page=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/page},%
        width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/width},%
        clip,%
        trim=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/left} \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/bottom} \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/right} \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/top},%
        ]{#2}%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\slidesH}[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/graphicx/.cd,left,right,top,bottom,page,#1}%
    \fbox{%
        \includegraphics[%
        page=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/page},%
        height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/width},%
        clip,%
        trim=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/left} \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/bottom} \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/right} \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/top},%
        ]{#2}%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\inputFile}{image.png}

\begin{document}

% \pgfkeys{
%   /testing/.cd,
%   scaling={height=10cm},
% }

\slidesS[left=1.8982075471698134cm, right=10cm, bottom=1cm, top=5.75cm, width=1]{\inputFile}
% \includegraphics[\testing]{\inputPdfFile}

\end{document}
```

the commented things are me trying to capture key+value of the `is choice`.

Any ideas on how to properly do this (using `\testing` in `\includegraphics` does not work, since `width=10cm` is perceived as an option, not as key=value I think)

Comment: There's always the "hammer" solution of write code that generate code. Not really recommended though because... TeX code is kind of ugly most of the time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is similar to the one using `expkv-cs`, but this time with `pgfkeys`. The idea remains the same: Only define the four keys `left`, `bottom`, `right`, `top`, and forward all unknown keys to `\includegraphics`. Just the forwarding part is a bit more complicated for `pgfkeys`. This answer doesn't incorporate the omission of `clip` and `trim` if they aren't necessary (if you want this I could build it in `pgfkeys` as well, just leave a comment).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/graphicx}
  {
    .is family
    ,left/.initial=0pt, left/.default=0pt
    ,bottom/.initial=0pt, bottom/.default=0pt
    ,right/.initial=0pt, right/.default=0pt
    ,top/.initial=0pt, top/.default=0pt
    ,.unknown/.code=%
      \edef\graphicwrap@unknown
        {%
          \unexpanded\expandafter{\graphicwrap@unknown},%
          \pgfkeyscurrentname
          \ifx\pgfkeysnovalue#1\else={\unexpanded{#1}}\fi
        }%
  }
\newcommand*\graphicwrap@unknown{}
\newcommand\graphicwrap[2][]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \pgfqkeys{/graphicx}{#1}%
      \expandafter\graphicwrap@\expandafter{\graphicwrap@unknown}{#2}%
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\graphicwrap@[2]
  {%
    \includegraphics
      [%
         clip
        ,trim=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/left}
              \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/bottom}
              \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/right}
              \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/top}
        ,#1%
      ]%
      {#2}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\graphicwrap[width=5cm, left=2cm]{example-image-duck}
\graphicwrap[scale=0.5, left=2cm]{example-image-duck}

% of course old names still work as well
\graphicwrap[clip, trim=2cm 0 0 0]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A version that only uses `clip` and `trim` if one of the keys were used (without a second layer of keys, instead by letting the keys do more than just storing their value):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/graphicx}
  {
    .is family
    ,left/.initial=0pt, left/.default=0pt
    ,bottom/.initial=0pt, bottom/.default=0pt
    ,right/.initial=0pt, right/.default=0pt
    ,top/.initial=0pt, top/.default=0pt
    ,left/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/graphicx/left}{#1}\let\graphicwrap@do\graphicwrap@clip
    ,bottom/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/graphicx/bottom}{#1}\let\graphicwrap@do\graphicwrap@clip
    ,right/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/graphicx/right}{#1}\let\graphicwrap@do\graphicwrap@clip
    ,top/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/graphicx/top}{#1}\let\graphicwrap@do\graphicwrap@clip
    ,.unknown/.code=%
      \edef\graphicwrap@unknown
        {%
          \unexpanded\expandafter{\graphicwrap@unknown},%
          \pgfkeyscurrentname
          \ifx\pgfkeysnovalue#1\else={\unexpanded{#1}}\fi
        }%
  }
\newcommand\graphicwrap@clip[1]
  {%
    \includegraphics
      [%
         clip
        ,trim=\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/left}
              \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/bottom}
              \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/right}
              \pgfkeysvalueof{/graphicx/top}
        ,#1%
      ]%
  }
\newcommand\graphicwrap@noclip[1]{\includegraphics[#1]}
\let\graphicwrap@do\graphicwrap@noclip
\newcommand*\graphicwrap@unknown{}
\newcommand\graphicwrap[2][]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \pgfqkeys{/graphicx}{#1}%
      \expandafter\graphicwrap@do\expandafter{\graphicwrap@unknown}{#2}%
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\graphicwrap[width=5cm, left=2cm]{example-image-duck}
\graphicwrap[scale=0.5, left=2cm]{example-image-duck}

% of course old names still work as well
\graphicwrap[clip, trim=2cm 0 0 0]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help (even implementing two solutions).
The `expkv-cs` solution looks pretty nice (I'm gonna definitely check out your package). But for now, I'd rather stick with `pgfkeys` (it's just what I already know). I don't think I'm gonna need the check for clip and trim (just passing 0cm to trim should suffice). But if it's not too much work I'd be interested how you do that ;)

Comment: @atticus you don't have to switch. `expkv-cs` can't do as much as `pgfkeys` can (the approach taken has serious limitations on versatility of keys, though most things can still be built in one way or the other). The approach for the detection is more or less the same as in the other answer, by adding an extra layer of keys. Another viable solution (for both) would be to detect whether all are either equivalent to `0` or equivalent to `0pt` (but writing that code would be more complicated).

Comment: @atticus alternative version using `clip` only if necessary posted. Please note that there was a small bug in the `.unknown` handler's code, the check for a key without a value was wrong.

Comment: Alright. Thanks again :+1

Answer (score 1):

The following uses `expkv-cs`, because setting up a small macro taking only a handful of keys is much easier there, imho (well, I'm the package author, so maybe not-so-humble, and pretty biased). Here it could be simpler by omitting the check whether `clip` and `trim` are necessary at all.

`expkv-cs` supports the special `...` key, meaning all unknown keys are collected there. This allows to easily forward unknown keys to `graphicx`. Drawback of this approach: If any of the `left`, `bottom`, `right`, or `top` keys are used they are put first in the key=value list of `\includegraphics`, so the order of keys isn't identical (which shouldn't be much of a problem).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{expkv-cs} % <- sorry, not pgfkeys here
\makeatletter
% optional argument grabbing, expkv-cs uses mandatory arguments
\newcommand\graphicwrap[1][]{\graphicwrap@{#1}}
% internal keys and their initial values here
\ekvcSplitAndForward\graphicwrap@\graphicwrap@do
  {
     internal-left   = 0pt      % #1
    ,internal-bottom = 0pt      % #2
    ,internal-right  = 0pt      % #3
    ,internal-top    = 0pt      % #4
    ,internal-any    = \@gobble % #5: used as a flag that clip is needed
    ,...                        % #6: unknown keys
  }
% additional keys (the front-facing ones) and what they do
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\graphicwrap@
  {
     meta left   = {internal-any=\@firstofone, internal-left   = {#1}}
    ,meta bottom = {internal-any=\@firstofone, internal-bottom = {#1}}
    ,meta right  = {internal-any=\@firstofone, internal-right  = {#1}}
    ,meta top    = {internal-any=\@firstofone, internal-top    = {#1}}
  }
% output macro
\newcommand\graphicwrap@do[7]
  {\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[#5{clip, trim=#1 #2 #3 #4}, #6]{#7}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\graphicwrap[width=5cm, left=2cm]{example-image-duck}
\graphicwrap[scale=0.5, left=2cm]{example-image-duck}

% of course old names still work as well
\graphicwrap[clip, trim=2cm 0 0 0]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For comparison, the following would be the variant without checking whether `clip` and `trim` are required:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{expkv-cs} % <- sorry, not pgfkeys here
\makeatletter
% optional argument grabbing, expkv-cs uses mandatory arguments
\newcommand\graphicwrap[1][]{\graphicwrap@{#1}}
% keys and their initial values here
\ekvcSplitAndForward\graphicwrap@\graphicwrap@do
  {
     left   = 0pt      % #1
    ,bottom = 0pt      % #2
    ,right  = 0pt      % #3
    ,top    = 0pt      % #4
    ,...               % #5: unknown keys
  }
% output macro
\newcommand\graphicwrap@do[6]{\includegraphics[clip, trim=#1 #2 #3 #4, #5]{#6}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\graphicwrap[width=5cm, left=2cm]{example-image-duck}
\graphicwrap[scale=0.5, left=2cm]{example-image-duck}

% of course old names still work as well
\graphicwrap[clip, trim=2cm 0 0 0]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```